# Why this error with pygbag: file not found in folder assets #python #pygbag

Tags: python, pygbag

When I run the localhost it will not work and the #debug says that there is an error and that it does not find the png files. I also put them into an assets folder, but it doesn't find them even if I try to figure out different solutions

Comment: first try to put your png files together with your main.py. Also use / as path separator never \

Comment: Also see if there are any errors in developer console...